# Adding data to subgroup layers with same name in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, group-layer

Assuming that I have an idealized .mxd TOC structure with group layers that contain group and subgroup layers which have the same name like in the following example:

**Layers**

- **GroupLayer1**

  - SubGroupLayer1

    - *Raster1.tif*
    - *Raster33.tif*
  - SubGroupLayer2

    - *Raster44.tif*
- **GroupLayer2**

  - SubGroupLayer1

    - *Raster2.tif*
    - *Raster4.tif*
  - SubGroupLayer2

    - *Raster7.tif*

Is it possible to add data using an 'absolute' layer path with ArcPy?

For example, if I want to add a raster layer `SampleRaster.tif` to the following place *GroupLayer2/SubGroupLayer2* : how could I do this in ArcPy?

I know how to add a group layer and then add the specific layer (e.g. solution in this question [Adding new group layer with ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/adding-new-group-layer-with-arcpy)) but have not found a solution how to add it if two layers have the same name.

My code that I have so far is pasted below

```
 # add rasters to .mxd project
    import arcpy

    arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\Data\Rasters'
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")

    for raster in rasters:
        # add raster to .mxd
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\Data\Test.mxd")
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

        # here I need to list the layers in the subgroup "SubGroupLayers2", but what to do when the subgroup layers names are equal? Is there a way to indicate an absolute path (e.g. Layers/GroupLayer2/SubGroupLayer2 here?)
        targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "SubGroupLayer2", df)[0]

        # I am then using another layer to apply the symbology to the raster and update the layer
        newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(raster)
        newlayer.visible = False
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, newlayer, "BOTTOM")
        updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, raster, df)[0]
        sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"D:\Data\Colormap.lyr")
        arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLayer, sourceLayer, True) 
        mxd.save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the group/subgroup path using the longName attribute:

...

```
targetGroupLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "SubGroupLayer2", df)[0]
print targetGroupLayer.longName
```

...

So you could loop through your targetGroupLayer list and create an if/then statement, based on the .longName, to find and insert layers to the specific group/subgroup.

Example code:

```
#Instead of using the index 0, return the whole list. 
grouplyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "SubGroupLayer2", df)
#Then loop through that list. 
for grplyr in grouplyrs: 
    if grplyr.longName == "GroupLayer2\SubGroupLayer2": # add your desired full path here, from examples 
        targetGroupLayer = grplyr
# return to your code in progress.
newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(raster)
newlayer.visible = False
arcpy.mapping.AddLayerToGroup(df, targetGroupLayer, newlayer, "BOTTOM")
...
```

Additional resources:

- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/addlayertogroup.htm#S2_GUID-4477AFDB-77CC-4524-8C9F-832D818AE292
- [Count number of group layers or Layers inside group layer using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178767/count-number-of-group-layers-or-layers-inside-group-layer-using-arcpy)
- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm

Comment: Could you give me a working example with the dummy dataset above, how would you incorporate the if statement?

Comment: Instead of using the index 0, return the whole list. Then loop through that list. e.g. `grouplyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "SubGroupLayer2", df); for grplyr in grouplyrs: if grplyr.longName == "": # add your desired full path here, from examples targetGroupLayer = grplyr`

Comment: Added this and some additional resources to the answer.